Go Create Http requests with Proxy
I have some code that uses a worker pool to request some API endpoints. Given a proxy in the format "IPADDR:PORT:USERNAME:PASSWORD" how can I create the request through this proxy? The proxy is only meant to reroute the request to the proxy server which then performs the actual API request.
The proxy can also look like:
resi.butterf.us:8000:gabe0:butterfly-country-US-region-Oregon-session-c5kfwefw7y

I tried creating a custom client, but that didn't work. I am implementing it wrong.
client := &http.Client{
   Transport: &http.Transport{
       Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
   },
}

func startWorkerPool(ctx context.Context, numWorkers, numRequests int) {

   //proxy
   ipaddr := "42.231.157.0"
   port := 61234
   username := "butterflyXX1"
   password := "leEbdwr71"

   var wg sync.WaitGroup
   work := make(chan string)

   for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
       wg.Add(1)
       go func(ctx context.Context) {
           defer wg.Done()
           client := http.Client{}
           for url := range work {
               if req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", url, nil); err != nil {
                   log.Println("err in req", err)
               } else if resp, err := client.Do(req); err != nil {
                   log.Println("err in req", err)
               } else {
                   resp.Body.Close()
               }
           }
       }(ctx)
   }

   // enqueue urls for workers and close the channel when done
   go func() {
       for i := 0; i < numRequests; i++ {
           work <- "https://httpbin.org/get"
       }
       close(work)
   }()

   // wait for workers to finish
   wg.Wait()
   log.Println("All requests processed")
}

